# keep cursor same position in field after requery

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to do a `autocomplete combobox` like this in the `keyUp` event.

```
Private Sub Combo59_KeyUp(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    If Len(Combo59.Text) > 2 Then
        Combo59.RowSource = "SELECT City FROM Mills WHERE City LIKE '%" & Combo59.Text & "%' GROUP BY City ORDER BY City;"
        Me.Dirty = False
        Combo59.Requery
    End If
End Sub
```

The problem is that after the requery, it selects all the text in the field so when the user press the next key, it erases everything.

Is there an easy way, or I have to find the cursor position and put it back after the requery?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may require some tweaking, but it should give you the general idea:

```
Private Sub Combo59_KeyUp(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
Dim SaveSelStart
    If Len(Combo59.Text) > 2 Then
        SaveSelStart = Combo59.SelStart
        Combo59.RowSource = "SELECT City FROM Mills WHERE City LIKE '%" & Combo59.Text & "%' GROUP BY City ORDER BY City;"
        Me.Dirty = False
        Combo59.Requery
        Combo59.SelLength = 0
        Combo59.SelStart = SaveSelStart
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you sir, it works like a charm. I thought there could be another solution or it was my way of doing the autocomplete that was really bad.

Comment: I just realized something. It doesn't allow me to do spaces. If I press space, the cursor goes back to the last letter. Do you have an idea why

Comment: Actualy it's the combobox that drops automatically the spaces.

Comment: Fixed, I changed the if statement for `If Len(Combo59.Text) > 2 And KeyCode <> 32 Then`.

Comment: I usually do this sort of "filter as you type" with text boxes so the space problem is not an issue. When I have had occasion to use combo boxes, I believe I handled it similar to how you did; i.e., make spaces a special case.